# Cannot Insert Null Values - Variable data not being stored in variables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm created a stored procedure which will be run as a job, but I'm getting an error that I will not be able to insert null values, although I'm setting values to my variables to using it in my update table statement. When I try to print the output statement, it is not being printed. Could you please help me with this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ABC].[RUN_PROCESS]
    (@JOBRUN_ID INT, @DATE DATE = NULL)
AS
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @StartDateTime  DATETIME = GETDATE()
    DECLARE @EndDateTime    DATETIME
    DECLARE @JobName        CHAR(6) = 'RUNPRO'
    DECLARE @JobID          INT = 100
    DECLARE @TaskID         INT
    DECLARE @TableID        INT
    DECLARE @Output         VARCHAR(2000)
    DECLARE @FailedCount    INT = 0
    DECLARE @TotalRecords   INT
    DECLARE @StudentID      INT
    DECLARE @TotalAmount    VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @UpdatedRecords INT
    DECLARE @Log2Entry      INT

    IF @DATE IS NULL
        SET @DATE = GETDATE()

    PRINT @DATE;

    -- Update entry in table [ABC].[LOG1_Table] with Status P
    UPDATE ABC.LOG1_Table 
    SET Status = 'P' 
    WHERE JobRunID = @JOBRUN_ID;
    
    -- Inserting a Log Entry in [ABC].[LOG2_Table]
    INSERT INTO ABC.LOG1_Table 
    VALUES (@JobID, @StartDateTime, @JobName, FORMAT(@StartDateTime, 'HH:mm'), '',NULL, 'A');
    
    SET @Log2Entry = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    
    SELECT @TotalRecords = COUNT(PaymentID) 
    FROM ABC.Student_Payments 
    WHERE Status <> 'X' AND PaymentDate = @Date;

    PRINT 'Total Payments to be Updated: '+ CAST(@TotalRecords AS VARCHAR(20));

    SELECT @TotalAmount = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), CAST(SUM(Charges + SalesTax) AS MONEY), 1) 
    FROM ABC.Student_Payments 
    WHERE Status <> 'X' AND PaymentDate = @Date;
    
    PRINT 'Total Amount: '+ @TotalAmount
    
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        UPDATE ABC.Student_Payments 
        SET DateReceived = GETDATE() 
        OUTPUT @JOBRUN_ID, inserted.PaymentID, 'Payment Received', GETDATE(), 'D' INTO ABC.LOG3_TABLE
        WHERE Status <> 'X' AND PaymentDate = @Date
        
        SET @UpdatedRecords = @@ROWCOUNT
        
        PRINT 'Total Payments Updated: '+ CAST(@UpdatedRecords AS VARCHAR(20));

        SELECT @Output = 'RUNPRO: Updated' + CAST(@UpdatedRecords AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' records for $' + @TotalAmount;

        PRINT (@Output);
        
        IF(@TotalRecords = @LockedRecords)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE ABC.LOG1_Table 
            SET OutputLog = @Output, 
                EndDateTime = @EndDateTime, 
                RunTime = CONVERT(decimal(7, 2), DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartDateTime, @EndDateTime)),  
                Status = 'C' 
            WHERE JobRunID = @JOBRUN_ID;
        
            UPDATE ABC.LOG2_Table 
            SET Remarks = @Output, 
                EndDateTime = @EndDateTime, 
                Status = 'C' 
            WHERE Log2Entry = @Log2Entry;           
        END
        ELSE
            RAISERROR('The Total Record Count and Locked Record Count Do not Match',12,100) 

    COMMIT TRANSACTION; 
        
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
   
    SELECT @EndDateTime = GETDATE();
    
    UPDATE ABC.LOG1_Table 
    SET OutputLog = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
        EndDateTime = @EndDateTime, 
        RunTime = CONVERT(decimal(7, 2), DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartDateTime, @EndDateTime)),  
        Status = 'E'  
    WHERE JobRunID = @JOBRUN_ID;
    
    UPDATE ABC.LOG2_Table  
    SET Remarks = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
        EndDateTime = @EndDateTime, 
        Status = 'E' 
    WHERE Log2Entry = @Log2Entry;

END CATCH
```

Comment: Where exactly do you declare `@ACCT_DATE`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning ..That's Date.

Comment: Do you know what line throws the error? Or at least if it is in LOG1_Table or LOG2_Table? It would be also useful if you update the question adding the table fileds scheme

Comment: @Carlos I'm setting summary of what has happened in the variable Output. And this variable, goes into the output log in LOG_1 Tables as input. It says cannot insert null values on Output log column in Log_1 Table. Even the variable Output is not being printed during execution

Comment: Can you change the line "SET aUpdatedRecords = aaROWCOUNT" to "SET aUpdatedRecords = isnull(aaROWCOUNT, 0)"?

Comment: @carlos It is still not working

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you get past this error:  "Must declare the scalar variable "@DATE"."   @Date is not declared in the code shown, but referenced 3 times.

Comment: I suggest you specify exact column names in insert statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that "Charges" field or "SalesTax" fields maybe admit null values. If so, please update this line:

```
SELECT @TotalAmount = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), CAST(SUM(Charges + SalesTax) AS MONEY), 1)
```

To:

```
SELECT @TotalAmount = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), CAST(isnull(SUM(Charges + SalesTax), 0) AS MONEY), 1)
```

So you will not have a NULL value and it would work fine.

Comment: @Carlos..Perfect..It worked. Thanks a lot! I've been at it for around 2 hrs now. Thanks a lot Carlos

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the fields in the INSERT statement.

This is most likely to be the problem,
if you're getting error that you cannot insert null values.

I see that currently the INSERT statement is without specifying fields
(from the code you've pasted).